# How to write in modbus device with Thingsboard RPC?

Tags: modbus, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I have a modbus device connected through tb-gateway, where I can read from device.

I'm strugling to use a RPC to write to device.  I read this doc thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rpc/#server-side-rpc-api and I can read from device.

Now I want to send a command to write in a tag and I read this doc thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rpc/#server-side-rpc-api but I don't know where to put modbus RPC code. The documentation is not clear for me.

Is someone using Thingsboard RPC to write in modbus devices?

Comment: SO does not work like that. You have to show your own effort/code in order to receive help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I know that and I'm really sorry, I just don't know how to start with it. I read this doc https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rpc/#server-side-rpc-api/ and I can read from device. 

Now I want to send a command and I read this doc https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rpc/#server-side-rpc-api/ but I don't know where to put modbus RPC code. The documentation is not clear for me.